# SharePoint 365 - creating workflow with dynamic approver name from InfoPath file

Tags: sharepoint, dynamic, workflow, infopath

Hello SharePoint ninjas!
Could you please advise me how to create the SharePoint 365 workflow for InfoPath for file that has dynamic approver1 name (by this I mean it directs the approval flow to user picked by people picker in InfoPath file).
The InfoPath file has been succesfully published on site's form library, user enters this file/form and after submission it creates an XML file. I want this XML file (with one of rows being the name of Approver1) be the object in the approval flow.

Thank you for advise,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: putting the field to column of Sharedrive, then 'Get user profile'.
To prevent dealing with array/for each I have used Parse JSON/Select.